# couchbaseSessionRepository in CouchbaseHttpSessionConfiguration required a bean of type 'com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket'

Tags: java, spring-boot, session, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I am trying to use @EnableCouchbaseHttpSession in one of the application to store the session in couchBase.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCouchbaseHttpSession(keepStringAsLiteral = true)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**CouchBase Coniguration**
@Configuration
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories
@Getter
public class CouchbaseConfigurations extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

```
    @Value("${couchbase.connectionString}")
    private String connectionString;

    @Value("${couchbase.username}")
    private String userName;

    @Value("${couchbase.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${couchbase.bucket}")
    private String bucketName;

}
```

**dependency Used**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.couchbaselabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-couchbase</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

After starting the application ,the appiation is not getting started with the error

**ERROR LOG**

> Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/session/SessionRepositoryFilterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springSessionRepositoryFilter' defined in org.springframework.session.data.couchbase.config.annotation.web.http.CouchbaseHttpSessionConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'springSessionRepositoryFilter' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'couchbaseSessionRepository' defined in org.springframework.session.data.couchbase.config.annotation.web.http.CouchbaseHttpSessionConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'couchbaseSessionRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
>
> **Parameter 0 of method couchbaseSessionRepository in org.springframework.session.data.couchbase.config.annotation.web.http.CouchbaseHttpSessionConfiguration required a bean of type 'com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket' that could not be found.
> Action:
> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket' in your configuration.**

Comment: Can anyone please answer before the question is eligible for bounty?

Comment: Hi, I'm in charge of the spring-session-data-couchbase, the latest release still relies on SDK 2.7, but the current one is 3.0 . I will work on a fix this week and let you know here once it is ready. Sorry for the long delay, I was on holidays ;)

Comment: Thanks for replying  @deniswsrosa Please message here once the issue is fixed. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Create a bean of type com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket in your application as from
spring boot version 2.3.X and above (spring-data-couchbase 4+), Bucket bean is no longer autoconfigured.

```
@Configuration
public class CouchbaseBucketConfig {
    private final CouchbaseClientFactory couchbaseClientFactory;

    public CouchbaseBucketConfig(CouchbaseClientFactory couchbaseClientFactory) {
        this.couchbaseClientFactory = couchbaseClientFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Bucket bucket(){
        return couchbaseClientFactory.getBucket();
    }
}
```

Add 'spring-session-data-couchbase' dependency in your POM.xml . Refer
[Github](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/spring-session-data-couchbase) , [Couchbase docs](https://docs.couchbase.com/tutorials/session-storage/java.html).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.couchbaselabs</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-data-couchbase</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This should solve the application start up issue.

[EXPECT FURTHER EDITS]